# Mirror Values from one Table in another Table for Quick Access in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, reference, mirror

I have a setup in which I assign text values of different types to some object. The system uses three tables, `types_table` storing the different types of values, `values_table` storing all values for all possible types and `assignments_table` storing the assignment of a type / value pair to some object referenced with an id.

The schema looks something like this

```
CREATE TABLE types_table        (type_id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, type_name TEXT)
CREATE TABLE values_table       (value_id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, type_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY, value_name TEXT )
CREATE TABLE assignments_table  (object_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY, type_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY, value_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY)
```

Now, there are two specific queries which I want to implement as efficiently as possible. The first one is:

- Give me all object_id for which type_id is <target_type> and value_id is <target_value>
- Give me all value_id for which type_id is <target_type>

The schema above has a problem I'm aware of. I'm storing the reference to the `type_id` in two places, once part of the assignment and once part of the value. The true location of the `type_id` reference / foreign key is in the `values_table`. However, without the duplicate in the `assignments_table`, the first query would require looking in two tables.

So I was wondering if there is a way in SQLite to "mirror" the `type_id` stored in the `values_table` in the `assignment_table` for quick access. I.e., these values never go out of sync but the first example query wouldn't require having to look up two tables.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "mirror" of a another table's column. The proper design is to remove `type_id` from `assignments_table` and keep only `value_id`.

Comment: @forpas Ok, that's all I wanted to know. If you write an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: It's fine, there is no need for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a JOIN

```
CREATE TABLE types_table        (type_id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, type_name TEXT)
CREATE TABLE values_table       (value_id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, type_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY, value_name TEXT )
CREATE TABLE assignments_table  (object_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY, value_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY)
```

Give me all object_id for which type_id is <target_type> and value_id is <target_value>

```
SELECT object_id
FROM asignmets_table 
LEFT JOIN values_table  using value_id
LEFT JOIN types_table  using type_id
WHERE type_name = ? AND value_name = ?
```

Give me all value_id for which type_id is <target_type>

```
SELECT value_id
FROM values_table
WHERE type_id = ?
```

and you can create a view for the assignments_table

```
CREATE VIEW assignments_view (object_id, type, value) AS
SELECT object_id, type_name, value_name
FROM assignments_tabe
JOIN values_table using values_id
JOIN types_table using type_id
```

you can than select from that view

```
SELECT object_id 
FROM assingments_view
WHERE type_name = ? AND value_name = ?
```

Comment: Ok, A view is probably the closes thing I was hoping fore. Not sure how much of a performance boost a view is but After some consideration, I think most performance requirements can be achieved by using indices at the right places.

Comment: primary key is always indexed.